# A way to capture the value of COUNT(*) in Python using mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a Python script to process a lot of SELECT statements of the form:

`SELECT count(*) FROM vdb.avd_032022 WHERE city = "OCEANSIDE" AND party = "DEM" AND district_id = "1920" AND email != "";`

I understand that the typical way of counting the number of rows in a table is to use Cursor.rowcount property. However, this property requires one to iterate through all rows with a counter. I get that count(*) might not be more efficient computationally, but parsing the actual output the mysql connector receives would be simpler.

Is there a way to retrieve the raw output from the connector? I don't know what that is, but the commandline mysql interface returns the following when running the above query:

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     4027 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.79 sec)

It might be easier to parse the total from that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `COUNT(*) AS total_count` ?

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: Have you done ANY SELECT queries with the selector?  This is no different.  You don't even NEED a column name.  You will get back a list of rows, where each row is a one-item tuple that contains the count.

Comment: code: 

result = cursor2022.execute(query)
ofile.write(query + " - " + str(result))

output: 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avd_032022.avd_032022 WHERE city = "OCEANSIDE" AND district_id = "1919" AND email != ""; - None,   

    I have also tried a number of other variations.

Comment: This worked:          try:
            cursor2022.execute(query)
            result = cursor2022.fetchall()

        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print("Error Processing SQL file", e)
            sys.exit(1)

        count = cursor2022.rowcount
        ofile.write(query + " - " + str(len(result)))

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
    try:
        cursor2022.execute(query)
        result = cursor2022.fetchall()

    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("Error Processing SQL file", e)
        sys.exit(1)

    ofile.write(query + " - " + str(len(result)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).